# Asking for help in proving a deduction based on theorem related to Functions with non-zero determinant

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus

I am self studying Ch-13( Implicit function and Extrememum Problems) of Tom M Apostol Mathematical Analysis.

I have a question in it.

Adding image : [image]

Now on next page author writes that Theorem 13.4 implies that a continuously differentiable function with a non-vanishing Jacobian at a point **a** has a local inverse in neighborhood of **a** .

> My question : how does only 1-1 implies that inverse exists in neighborhood of **a**. Why is onto not necessary here?

I have read a theorem which tells a monotonic and 1-1 function implies inverse exists. But here Partial derivaties are non - zero is no where given ( Theorem 13.4) . So, how can I deduce that local inverse exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $U$ is the open nbhd on which the function is one-one. Then you look at restriction of $ f$ as $f_U :U \rightarrow f(U) $ which is one-one and onto. Thus you have inverse in the nbhd.